# Latex Tikz align children vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have a simple tree. I cannot figure out how to align children vertically.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {0}
        child {node {a}}
        child {node {b}}
        child {node {c} 
            child {node {a1}}
            child {node {b1}}
            child {node {c1}}
            child {node {d1}}
        }
        child {node {d}}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Compiling the code gives a subtree under node c, but I want x and x1 to align vertically.
Do I have to manually place every node? Options like `below of=a` miss align the remaining children. I'm looking for something like `leftalign` whole tree.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: What is "x" and "x1" in your MWE? Do you mean something like `\node {0} [grow=right] ... `? Or maybe you want `[level 2/.style={every node/.style={xshift=-7.5mm}}]` (as option to the `tikzpicture`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what you want, but you can shift the nodes of a certain level to the left and right (since the default sibling distance is 15mm, in order to vertically align the nodes, you would need to shift all nodes by the half of this value which is 7.5mm):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 2/.style={every node/.style={xshift=-7.5mm}}]
    \node {0} 
        child {node {a}}
        child {node {b}}
        child {node {c} 
            child {node {a1}}
            child {node {b1}}
            child {node {c1}}
            child {node {d1}}
        }
        child {node {d}}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Variations of the above if one node is missing:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 2/.style={sibling distance=22.5mm, every node/.style={xshift=-7.5mm}}]
    \node {0} 
        child {node {a}}
        child {node {b}}
        child {node {c} 
            child {node {a1}}
            child {node {b1}}
            child {node {d1}}
        }
        child {node {d}}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 2/.style={every node/.style={xshift=-7.5mm}}]
    \node {0} 
        child {node {a}}
        child {node {b}}
        child {node {c} 
            child {node {a1}}
            child {node {b1}}
            child[missing] {}
            child {node {d1}}
        }
        child {node {d}}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Maybe, you could also try the `forest` package:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} for tree={node options={text width=1.25em, align=center}}
 [0
    [a] 
    [b] 
    [c
        [a1]
        [b1]
        [c1, calign with current]
        [d1]
    ] 
    [d]
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}    
\begin{forest} for tree={node options={text width=1.25em, align=center}}
 [0
    [a] 
    [b] 
    [c
        [a1]
        [b1]
        [, phantom, calign with current]
        [d1]
    ] 
    [d]
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I want

Comment: what if, I don't have c1(or any other node on level2) and want to have each level have the same width?

Comment: You may ask this new question in another post.

Comment: @Chelz See my edit ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you. I was afraid, that I had to compute xshift and sibling distance manually, but that's the best solution for now.